# How to use getChildAt(..) on an Android Compound Control

Tags: android

I have a ViewGroup inside a layout inside my XML. It has children defined under it. In the ViewGroup, I can easily use getChildAt(..) to go through the children defined in XML.

activity_main.xml:

```html
<Layout>
  <ViewGroup>
     <Child1> ...
  </ViewGroup>
</Layout>
```

I want to replace that ViewGroup with a Compound Control that has a ViewGroup and some other controls. But I still need to be able to access its children.

I.e.
activity_main.xml:

```html
<Layout>
  <CompoundControl>
     <Child1>...
  </CompoundControl>
</Layout>
```

compound_control.xml:

```html
<Layout>
  <ViewGroup>
  <Buttons or something>
</Layout>
```

But new if I call getChildAt(..) in the class for the compound control, of course it looks for children in compoun_control.xml, not children in activity_main.xml. Is there a way around this? Thank you.

Comment: viewGroup.getChildAt(..) gets a child of this viewGroup, do you want to get grand children or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the custom compound_control viewgroup and its children accessible in the activity class corresponding to the main_activity.xml. So you can give id to your compound control when replacing it with the viewgroup in main_activity . Later on if you want to access custom viewgroup you can get reference from the activity class. like

```
 <Layout>
    <CompoundControl id="xyz">
    <Child1>...
    </CompoundControl>
    </Layout>
```

This id can be fetched in its activity class like.

```
 CompoundControl a = (CompoundControl)findViewById(R.id.xyz);
    a.getChildAt(..);
```